# Having trouble installing KDCircularProgress Xcode 9

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, kdcircularprogress

I want to install KDCircularProgress I've tried Cocoapods and adding .swift file to the project but I get two errors for that

> Property cannot be marked @IBInspectable because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C

and

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: The code is not ready to be used with Swift 4. You can try to fix it manually and address a pull request or just wait for it to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In the right side in inspector inherit from class KDCircularProgressView try using

```
@IBOutlet var circularProgressView: KDCircularProgress!
```